# Список файлов с датой создания файлов

Tags: php

Добрый день. Требуется вывести список файлов с информацией о дате создания каждого файла. Код:

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('img/')) {
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
{
if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
echo "$entry | ";
echo date("F d Y H:i:s.",filectime("$entry"));
echo "<br>";
} }
closedir($handle); }
?>
```

Выдаёт результат:

```
Снимок экрана от 2014-09-24 14:27:26.png | January 01 1970 07:00:00.
Снимок экрана от 2014-05-26 10:53:18.png | January 01 1970 07:00:00.
Снимок экрана от 2013-11-01 14:34:43.png | January 01 1970 07:00:00.
Снимок экрана от 2014-09-14 20:04:37.png | January 01 1970 07:00:00.
Снимок экрана от 2014-07-02 09:31:16.png | January 01 1970 07:00:00.
Снимок экрана от 2013-10-14 13:55:10.png | January 01 1970 07:00:00.
```

Но если указывать имя файла принудительно - всё замечательно.
Подскажите, как заставить выводить дату нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так замени на

```
filectime('img/'.$entry)
```

и всё будет прекрасно :)

upd: а я бы сделал вот так

```
if ($open = scandir('img')) {
    foreach ($open as $k => $v) {
        if ($v != "." && $v != "..") {
            echo $v . ' | ' . date('F d Y H:i:s', @filectime('img/' . $v))."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как всегда - невнимательность меня погубит. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (new \DirectoryIterator('img') as $item) {
    if (!$item->isFile()) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $item->getFilename();
    echo ' | ';
    echo date('F d Y H:i:s.', $item->getCTime());
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

а вот это

```
filectime("$entry")
```

вообще-то даст тот же результат, что и

```
filectime($entry)
```